# How to get blob name and use as parameter or variable for next activity in Data Factory V2

Tags: parameters, blob, azure-data-factory, dynamic-content

I am running a Data Factory v2 pipeline, as part of the process it saves a file to Azure blob storage, and renames it using a powershell runbook that gets triggered by a web(hook) activity in the same pipeline.

I need to read the content of the file, and to do that I run a function as part of the pipeline.

How can I grab the filename in storage (I have a dataset for the storage), and use, or pass the name of that file to the next activity (the function) so it can read the file?

I have tried a metadata lookup and got the first part of the filename based on the name its saved as in storage before its renamed (it has the date appended to it), which is all I need, but how can I reference the output of that metadata lookup and pass onto the function activity? Can I use a 'like' in dynamic content for the function? I'd be happy to get the name of the file in storage based on a `'filename like'`

I'm open to any ideas. I don't necessarily need the whole name of the file, if I could do something such as a like or contains in ADF dynamic content I could use the output of the metadata lookup, I just don't know how, or if that is allowed or possible. Could I use `'startswith'`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document shows how to use look up activity result in the next activity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#use-the-lookup-activity-result-in-a-subsequent-activity

You can reference the output in the header or payload body of web activity.

In your case, if you want to filter the filename list you may try filter activity after lookup activity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-filter-activity